# A question to a proof regarding to measurable functions with basic topology

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

I have a question regarding the following proof(Thm 1.8 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis). I can see why R is the cartesian product of two open segments I1 and I2, but I don't understand how this translates into the next line. Why is it an intersection? Can someone explain?

[image]

Comment: $$z \in f^{-1}(R) \\
\iff f(z) = (u(z),v(z)) \in I_1 \times I_2 \\
\iff (u(z) \in I_1) \land (v(z) \in I_2) \\
\iff (z \in u^{-1}(I_1) \land z \in v^{-1}(I_2)) \\$$

Answer (score 0):

For any map it holds that $f^{-1}(A \cap B) = f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$. We can use this for $R$ since it can be written as an intersection of two sets: $R = I_1 \times I_2 = (I_1\times \Bbb{R}) \cap (\Bbb{R}\times I_2)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(R) &= f^{-1}((I_1\times \Bbb{R}) \cap (\Bbb{R}\times I_2)) \\
&= f^{-1}(I_1\times \Bbb{R}) \cap f^{-1}(\Bbb{R}\times I_2)\\
&= u^{-1}(I_1) \cap v^{-1}(I_2).
\end{align*}